# Calling methods dynamically, but not from a custom class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple loop that prints out all available values of dir("Hello") side by side with the help("Hello".xxx) for each dir returned.

I've seen a number of stackoverflow threads on calling functions dynamically from a custom class, but it's not so clear how I can loop through built-in methods.

Taking this as an example:

```
for dr in dir("Hello"):
```

Using 'format' converts the `"Hello.%d" % dr` into a string of "hello.upper", but the print(help('hello.upper')) fails, because the help function expects "hello".upper, not "hello.upper":

```
for dr in dir("Hello"):
    print(dr)
    print(help("Hello.%d" % dr))
```

I've tried researching getattr, but the `help` function is not a method of the string, so `getattr("Hello", "help")("upper")` isn't working either.

expected results are:

dir value (followed by:)

dir help output

Comment: What is `dir("Hello")` supposed to mean?

Comment: dir("Hello") returns all the methods available to that string.

Answer (score 0):

[`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) doesn't return a string, it opens an interactive viewer for reading the help page.

To view each of these pages for some object (warning: there are going to be a lot of these pages), you can use `getattr` to get the attribute of the object given its name

```
obj = "Hello"

for attr_name in dir(obj):
    help(getattr(obj, attr_name))
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrick - that's my problem solved.  I didn't realise you could use getattr within 'help' itself.

Comment: This is the same as doing `var = getattr(obj, attr_name)` and then `help(var)`.  `help` is a function like any other and there are no special rules around calling it.